# .filterDate is not function

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, filter, feature-filter

I'm having an error while trying to filter a dataset by date with the function .filterDate().
My dataset is as follow : [image]
[image]

I'm using this function in the code below :

```
var zonalStatsL = intervals.map(function(i) {
  // Calculate temporal composite.
  var startRangeL = ee.Date(startDate).advance(i, intervalUnit);
  var endRangeL = startRangeL.advance(interval, intervalUnit);
  var temporalStat = simpleJoinedCollectionL.filterDate(startRangeL, endRangeL)
                              .reduce(temporalReducer);
```

You can find my full code here : https://code.earthengine.google.com/b40aa5cd852add22973be03561515ca0

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that variable `simpleJoinedCollectionL` is not an instanceof `ee.ImageCollection`. So the `filterDate()` is not available. It can be solved simply converting that to image collection will do the job. Check the following snippet to do the same.

```
var simpleJoinedCollectionL = ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoinedCollectionL);
var temporalStat = simpleJoinedCollectionL.filterDate(startRangeL, endRangeL);
```